# Trying to match two variables that both contain special characters in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

So here is a weird problem. I have a ton of scripts that are executed by "master" scripts and I need to verify that what is in the "master" is valid. Problem is, these scripts contain special characters and I need to match them to make sure the "Master" is referencing the correct scripts.

An example of one file might be

```
Example's of file names (20160517) [test].sh
```

Here is what my code looks like. `@MasterScipt` is an array where each element is a filename of what I expect the sub-scripts to be named.

```
opendir( DURR, $FileLocation );    # I'm looking in a directory where the subscripts reside

foreach ( readdir(DURR) ) {

    for ( my $j = 0; $j != $MasterScriptlength; $j++ ) {
        $MasterScipt[$j] =~ s/\r//g;
        print "DARE TO COMPARE\n";
        print "$MasterScipt[$j]\n";
        print "$_\n";

        #I added the \Q to quotemeta, but I think the issue is with $_
        #I've tried variations like
        #if(quotemeta($_) =~/\Q$MasterScipt[$j]/){
        #To no avail, I also tried using eq operator and no luck :(
        if ( $_ =~ /\Q$MasterScipt[$j]/ ) {
            print "WE GOOD VINCENT\n";
        }
    }
}

closedir(DURR);
```

No matter what I seem to do, my output will always look like this

```
DARE TO COMPARE
Example's of file names (20160517) [test].sh
Example's of file names (20160517) [test].sh
```

Comment: If I were you I would use a named `my` variable instead of `$_` like so `while ( my $file = readdir(DURR) ) { ... }`. Many operators act on `$_`, and while your code may work now, a simple change in the future may break it for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I was staring at this thing for too long, and I think writing this question out helped me answer it.

Not only did I need to add `\Q` in my regex, but there was a whitespace character. I did a `chomp` to both `$_` and `$MasterScipt[$j]` and now its working.

Comment: Trying to articulate a question well is a way toward finding an answer to it :)

Comment: There's no need to `chomp $_`: the values returned by `readdir` don't have a newline at the end. It would also be better to replace both `chomp` and `s/\r//` with `s/\s+\z//`, as presumably the contents of `@MasterScipt` come from a manually-created file, and it is quite possible that the file has spurious whitespace at the end of some of the lines

Comment: We are all [rubber ducks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) here... :)

Comment: @serenesat: The privilege of editing posts is restricted to subscribers with 2,000+ experience points because you are supposed to be responsible with the facility by now. Removing *"Thanks"* from the end of an answer is not an improvement in any way, and would have been rejected if you still had to submit your changes for peer review. Please don't edit posts to make insignificant changes.

Comment: @Borodin: _Thanks_ is consider as noise because it is not relevant to the post. So I removed it. I  have read on Meta StackOverflow that ***Anything that is not relevant to the post is noise and should be removed. That includes salutations, signatures, 'thanks'.***

Comment: @serenesat: While the "Thanks" should never have been in the post in the first place, the general consensus on Meta is that removing it should be done only as part of a substantive edit that makes a significant and useful change to the post. Did it cause you problems with understanding what was written? Or do you think it altered the meaning so that what was said was incorrect? I seriously doubt it. You could have had a useful effect by writing a comment that explained to the OP that such decorations are inappropriate. Without it all they would see is a churlish and pointless amendment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that your code should look more like this. The main changes are that I have used a named variable `$file` for the values returned by `readdir`, and I iterate over the *contents* of the array `@MasterScipt` instead of its indexes because `$j` is never used in your own code except to access the array elements

```
s/\s+\z// for @MasterScipt;

opendir DURR, $FileLocation or die qq{Unable to open directory "$FileLocation": $!};

while ( my $file = readdir DURR ) {

    for my $pattern ( @MasterScipt ) {

        print "DARE TO COMPARE\n";
        print "$pattern\n";
        print "$file\n";

        if ( $file =~ /\Q$pattern/ ) {
            print "WE GOOD VINCENT\n";
        }
    }
}

closedir(DURR);
```

But this is a simple `grep` operation and it can be written as such. This alternative builds a single regular expression that will match any of the items in `@MasterScipt` and uses `grep` to build a list of all values returned by `readdir` that match it

```
s/\s+\z// for @MasterScipt;

my @matches = do {

    my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @MasterScipt;

    opendir my $dh, $FileLocation or die qq{Unable to open directory "$FileLocation": $!};

    grep { /$re/ } readdir $dh;
};
```